# Cisco Kron Job starts later and later

Tags: cisco, troubleshooting, cli, ntp

I use a Kron job to ring a shit bell for our manufacturing plant. The application works, but the job starts 35+ seconds late.  The problem seems to be getting worse, a few days ago it was at 35 secs now it's up to 47 secs.  I did a full debug of Kron but it really doesn't get to the source of why it starts late.  What are some useful debugs I can use to sort this out?

The clock is synchronized:

```
CMERouter#sh clock
06:14:53.057 CDT Thu Apr 29 2021

CMERouter#sh ntp status
Clock is synchronized, stratum 3, reference is 171.66.97.126
nominal freq is 250.0000 Hz, actual freq is 249.9885 Hz, precision is 2**24
reference time is E4350DE9.22295565 (05:50:17.133 CDT Thu Apr 29 2021)
clock offset is 0.0020 msec, root delay is 0.05 msec
root dispersion is 0.05 msec, peer dispersion is 0.01 msec
loopfilter state is 'CTRL' (Normal Controlled Loop), drift is 0.000045786 s/s
system poll interval is 1024, last update was 1486 sec ago.
CMERouter#
```

This the job:

```
kron occurrence ShiftChange1 at 6:00 recurring
policy-list ShiftChange

kron policy-list ShiftChange
 cli csim start 7777
!
```

Here is the start of the debug of the Kron Job:

```
Apr 29 06:00:47.394 CDT: Major 1, Minor 0
Apr 29 06:00:47.394 CDT: Timer Event ShiftChange1
Apr 29 06:00:47.394 CDT: Kron delay for next ShiftChange1 86400000
Apr 29 06:00:47.394 CDT: Call parse_cmd 'csim start 7777'
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: csim: called number = 7777, loop count = 1 ping count = 0

Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: csimSetupPeer peer type(2), destPat(7777), matched(4), target()
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: //-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CCAPI/ccCallSetupRequest:  Destination=, Calling IE Present=FALSE, Mode=0, Outgoing Dial-peer=7777, Params=0x47C5482C, Progress Indication=NULL(0)
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: //-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CCAPI/ccCheckClipClir: In: Calling Number=(TON=Unknown, NPI=Unknown, Screening=Not Screened, Presentation=Allowed)
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: //-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CCAPI/ccCheckClipClir:
   Out: Calling Number=(TON=Unknown, NPI=Unknown, Screening=Not Screened, Presentation=Allowed)
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: //-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CCAPI/ccCallSetupRequest:
   Destination Pattern=7777, Called Number=7777, Digit Strip=FALSE
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: //-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CCAPI/ccCallSetupRequest:
   Calling Number=(TON=Unknown, NPI=Unknown, Screening=Not Screened, Presentation=Allowed), Called Number=7777(TON=Unknown, NPI=Unknown), Redirect Number=, Display Info=
   Account Number=, Final Destination Flag=FALSE,
   Guid=FC7E9050-A810-11EB-91C8-E1B9F2977CF7, Outgoing Dial-peer=7777
Apr 29 06:00:47.402 CDT: //-1/xxxxxxxxxxxx/CCAPI/cc_api_display_ie_subfields:
   ccCallSetupRequest:
   cisco-username=
   ----- ccCallInfo IE subfields -----
   cisco-ani=
   cisco-anitype=0
   cisco-aniplan=0
   cisco-anipi=0
   cisco-anisi=0
   dest=7777
   cisco-desttype=0
   cisco-destplan=0
   cisco-rdie=FFFFFFFF
   cisco-rdn=
   cisco-lastrdn=
   cisco-rdntype=-1
   cisco-rdnplan=-1
   cisco-rdnpi=-1
   cisco-rdnsi=-1
   cisco-redirectreason=-1   fwd_final_type =0
   final_redirectNumber =
   hunt_group_timeout =0
```

Comment: The primary purpose of a router is to route packets between networks as fast as possible, and anything else is secondary to that. Other features and functions will be delayed in order to route packets if the router gets busy. What you are doing should really be set up on a cheap, dedicated PC.

Comment: The only thing this router does is this app.  Thanks for taking the time to read and offering a comment.